# General Topology: Showing no sequence converges to an element of $X^+$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

[image]

I'm looking for some help with question 3-9 (which uses some information from question 3-8). The showing that $z$ is in the closure of $X^+$ is pretty straight-forward. The bit I'm struggling with is showing that there is no sequence of elements in $X^+$ converging to $z$. My approach is to assume there is such a sequence. If there is such a sequence $(x_i) \subset X^+$, then for all neighborhoods $U$, of $z$, there exists some $N>0$ such that $x_i \in U$ for all $i \geq N$. In particular, it must hold for $U=(U_1,U_2,...)$ where $U_k:=(-1/k,1/k)$. From here, I'm not quite able to get the contradiction I want. Is this approach salvageable?

Comment: The neighborhood you give is not quite salvageable, but you are thinking along essentially the right lines. You need your open set $U$ to be based on the sequence $x_i$. More specifically, try picking $U_i$ to exclude $x_i$.

Comment: Instead of defining $U_k$ as you have done, use the sequence $(x_i)$ to define it (as in Cantor's diagonal argument)

Comment: I think I see. How about letting $U_k:=(-x_{k}/2,x_{k}/2)$ ?

Comment: Since $x_k \in X^+$ it is a sequence, not a real number, so that $U_k$ doesn't really make sense.  Instead, consider the $k$th component of $x_k$

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Let me use more precise notation and call $x^{m}_{n}$ the $m$th term of the $n$th sequence. Then I can define $U_k:= (-x^{k}_{k} /2, x^{k}_{k} /2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y_n=(y_{n,j})_{j\in\Bbb N} \in X^+$ for each $n\in \Bbb N.$ For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $$f(n)=\frac {1}{2}y_{n,n}.$$ Let $U=\prod_{n\in \Bbb N}(-f(n),f(n)).$

Then $U$ is a nbhd of $z$ which is disjoint from $\{y_n:n\in \Bbb N\},$ because for each $n$ we have $y_{n,n}\not \in (-f(n),f(n)).$ So $z$ is not in the closure of $\{y_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$ so $(y_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ cannot be converging to $z.$

Comment: It is easy to show that $X$ is a $T_m$ space for $m\le 3\frac {1}{2}.$ It is unknown whether $X$ is a $T_4$ (normal) space.